# how to Remove the default navigation bar button

Tags: iphone, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

i am using a pushviewcontroller for navigation and i am getting default back button on the navigation bar..... i am trying to hide that default button and make my navigation bar plain.....anybody know how to hide that default navigation button on left side of the screen

Answer (score 21, accepted):

In the viewDidLoad method of the view controller that is being pushed, you should set the hidesBackButton property of the navigationItem to YES:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = YES;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to set `self.title = @"";` just before using pushViewcontroller method.

Answer (score 1):

Just like the previous answer: set the `hidesBackButton` property in the `viewDidLoad` method.
Can also hide the back button in the event of another action after the view is loaded using
animation

```
[self.navigationItem setHidesBackButton:flag animated:flag]
```